# Javascript dropdown loop does not seem to loop

Tags: javascript

I have two dropdowns. When selecting a value from the first (bron) I want to select an entry from the second. 
This is fired from the onChange of the first dropdown.

```
function DepId() {
    var bron = document.getElementById("IDUserDepartment");
    var doel = document.getElementById("IDDepartment");
    var bronwaarde = bron.options[bron.selectedIndex].value;
    for ( var i = 0; i < doel.options.length; i++ ) {
        var doelwaarde = doel.options[i].value;
        if ( doelwaarde == bronwaarde ) {
            doel.options[i].selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. 
EDIT: for whatever reason, I never get a match. When I hardcode any of the values, and then do: doel.options[hardcodedvalue].selected=true, the option is selected. When I test for window.alert(doelwaarde) inside the loop, this always returns zero.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Define "does not work."  What happens when you step through this in a debugger?  Are there any errors?  Does the code run at all?  Are the elements found?  Where in the logic does it fail?

Comment: It doesn't work because the var names aren't English, everyone knows var names have to be English in javascript.

Comment: andygoestohollywood : That's almost the most stupid answer I ever got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, I see nothing wrong with it. If I may make three suggestions:

1. You might want to use jQuery: simpler code, better multi-browser support.
2. Use console.log instead of a window alert for debugging purposes: less intrusive, won't interrupt your testing (have a look at the developer console of your browser).
3. You might want to use English names for your variables, controls, etc. More developers will be able to read it, besides English is often shorter than Dutch ;)

Comment: Code did work. Problem was in the option values. They had a whitespace in them.... problem solved. Thanks